# Example of a Covariance Matrix?

Tags: matrices, statistics, covariance

Can someone provide an example of a covariance matrix for any set of data? For example, if given:

2 3 4

5 1 8

9 7 6

how would I take this 3x3 matrix and convert it to the covariance matrix? I see the formula involves taking the means, but I'm not quite sure how that works in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a session from R statistical software with means and
variances of three variables *similar* to yours, and then a variance-covariance
matrix of all three.

```
x1 = c(2,3,4)
x2 = c(5,8,1)
x3 = c(9,7,5)
mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x3)
## 3                         # sample mean of x1
## 4.666667
## 7
var(x1); var(x2); var(x3)
## 1                         # sample variance of x1
## 12.33333
## 4
cbind(x1, x2, x3)            # puts 3 column vectors into matrix
       x1 x2 x3
##[1,]  2  5  9
##[2,]  3  8  7
##[3,]  4  1  5
cov(cbind(x1,x2,x3))         # makes covariance matrix from data matrix
##    x1       x2 x3
## x1  1 -2.00000 -2
## x2 -2 12.33333  4
## x3 -2  4.00000  4
```

Notice that the variance $1$ of data vector $x_1$ is in the
upper-left corner of the variance-covariance matrix. And
that the other two variances 12.3333 and 4 are also on the
principal diagonal of the matrix.

The covariance of $x_1$ and $x_3$ is computed as
$$S_{13} = \frac{(2-3)(9-7)+(3-3)(7-7)+(4-3)(5-7)}{2} = \frac{-2+0-2}{2} -4/2 = -2,$$
which is shown at the top of right-hand column of the variance-covariance
matrix. (Also again, at the left of the bottom row.)

You do not show the formula for the covariance as given in your book
so I have shown the arithmetic without trying to guess the notation.
I will leave it to you to match my arithmetic with the formula in your book.

Comment: I actually just came up with those values off the top of my head, was mostly just looking for the explanation of the formula and how it applied to the matrix itself, which is exactly what you did. Thank you!